# What does the B in BIO stand for?

Tags: openssl

OpenSSL uses an I/O abstraction called [BIO](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bio.html), but nowhere in the documentation I can find does it say what the B stands for (IO is obviously input/output).  Various websites suggest that the B stands for *basic* or *buffered*, but these are things like blog posts and forum posts without any degree of authority.

Does anyone have an official citation from the documentation, source code, or an OpenSSL developer on exactly what it stands for?

Comment: IIRC, it stands for basic. It was created by the original SSLeay team of Tim Hudson and Eric A. Young, neither of which is still associated with the project.

Comment: i'm taking a shot in the dark and going with binary or bits or bytes, leaning toward bytes :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basic Input Output.  According to [RSA's BIO SSL Functions description](http://www.rsa.com/products/bsafe/documentation/sslcme10refmanhtml/group__BIO__SSL__FUNCS.html).

Comment: Well that's not quite official OpenSSL documentation, but unless someone finds something better, that will have to do for now.

Comment: bio - Basic I/O abstraction https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/bio.html

Comment: updated link https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/bio.html