# How to prevent ::send() from throwing exception when calling write

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl, network-programming

I'm using OpenSSL and calling `SSL_write()`, which eventually calls `::send()`. However, occasionally when there's too much traffic the other side disconnects. Consequently on my next write `::send()` throws an exception.

I'd prefer to avoid this and return an error code so I can restart my application.

If I was calling `::send()` myself I could pass the flag `MSG_NOSIGNAL` which causes `::send()` to return an error code. However, I don't see such an argument for `SSL_write()`.

Is there anything I can do instead?

Comment: OpenSSL is a C library, and C does not have exceptions.  Nor does [Linux `send()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html) throw exceptions.  Where are you getting a `::send()` that throws exceptions?

Comment: Can you check if the handle is writable before actually sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... prevent ::send() from throwing exception

You likely mean triggering the signal SIGPIPE, not "throwing exception".

If you want to have full control over the input and output of the SSL stack use your own [BIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672133/what-are-openssl-bios-how-do-they-work-how-are-bios-used-in-openssl).

If you want to globally over all sockets get EPIPE returned instead of SIGPIPE triggered simply  set the signal handler for SIGPIPE to SIG_IGN. If you want to control SIGPIPE for a single socket you can do this with setsockopt on some systems. See [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly).